# Getting numbers from xml element with regex

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have element that have two numbers, separated by [-], for example 120-125.
Now using xslt I want to get these two numbers and create the xml elements with these value, and finally I want something like this:

```
<first>120</first>
<second>125</second>
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT

My xml structure to change looks like this:

```
<issue>
    <number>3</number>
    <year>2017</year>
    <article>
        <title>Title</title>
        <author>
            <firstname>name</firstname>
        </author>
        <pages>71-72</pages>
        <reference>reference</reference>
    </article>
</issue>
```

XSLT:

```
<issue>
    <number>
        <xsl:value-of select="number"/>
    </number>
    <year>
        <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
    </year>
    <xsl:for-each select="article">
        <article>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </title>
            <author>
                <firstname>
                    <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
                </firstname>
            </author>
            <xsl:template match="pages">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <first>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-')" />
                    </first>
                    <second>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '-')" />
                    </second>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
            <reference>
                <xsl:value-of select="reference"/>
            </reference>
        </article>
    </issue>
```

Output XML that I want to have:

```
<issue>
    <number>3</number>
    <year>2017</year>
    <article>
        <title>Title</title>
        <author>
            <firstname>name</firstname>
        </author>
        <first>71</first>
        <second>71</second>
        <reference>reference</reference>
    </article>
</issue>
```

Comment: You can try using `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions of XSLT 1.0 to split the string.

Comment: If you're using XSLT 1.0 then regular expressions aren't available, but you can still solve the problem easily as @AniketV suggests.

Comment: @AniketV How can I place content of xml element as first parameter of substring-before()? I tried something like this but it is not working: <xsl:value-of select="substring-before({pages}, '-')" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a `<xsl:template match="pages">` inside `<xsl:for-each>`. Considering the XSL that you have shared, you need to modify it as below. I have just modified the code for splitting the value of `<pages>`. The rest of your code remains unchanged.

```
<xsl:for-each select="article">
    <article>
        ...
        <first><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(pages, '-')" /></first>
        <second><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(pages, '-')" /></second>
        ...
    </article>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Can I use it between xml tags? Because it is not working actually.

Comment: Modified the answer to split the value of `<pages>` into separate child nodes for `<pages>`

Comment: Edited the post and added sample of my xslt file, the change of pages to separated xml elements are not only xslt tranfsormation that I am making.

Comment: Can you share the input XML that you wish to transform? I believe the XML that you have shared is the desired output.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I didn't change xml element of pages. I can not send the orginal data so I am making some small samples. The problem is that I am not taking only <pages> element from input xml, but other elements too, and the code you sent I think is desired to take only one element <pages> so it is not working. <pages> element is between other xml elements that I am taking and I think thats the problem. Could you change the xslt that will make that problem doable?